# Traveling Europe after 6-month Spain student visa (Type D) expires

Tags: long-stay-visas

I'm a US national in Spain on a student visa which expires on June 2. After that, I was hoping to visit some friends in Germany, Poland and Romania (in that order) over the course of two weeks before returning to the US via either Spain (if re-entry is possible) or Portugal.

I'm a very confused as to how 90/180 works after the expiry of a type-D visa. I've heard that the 90/180 counter starts upon the expiry of the visa, but some people have said its better to exit Schengen and to get stamped as a tourist/visitor.

So, two main questions:

1. Will I be able to just travel as normal around the Schengen area after my student visa expires, will I have to do some weird in-and-out trip? Or is a further stay in Schengen not actually legal?
2. If I overstay my Spanish visa by a week before flying out, is there any precedent for penalties? If I left the Schengen zone before the visa expired, would I legally be allowed reentry into Spain as a tourist?